# How to fix the audio output now? After restart it works once or twice and then stop working sound

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, vlc

Everytime after restart the system it works and then suddently my sound output stop working.

```
sun@sun-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ speaker-test 

speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
```

EDIT

```
sun@sun-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ alsactl init
Found hardware: "USB-Audio" "USB Mixer" "USB046d:082d" "" ""
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
sun@sun-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ speaker-test 

speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
sun@sun-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem for quite sometime but it happens more in between for me. The solution has always been to restart Alsa from the CLI when it does happen.

```
alsactl init
```

This should restart the alsa system and re-initialize your audio hardware.

Comment: jfreak53: but i have always alsa problem, i have to run `alsactl init` in a crontab?

Comment: See my EDIT above plz. Its not starting still.